# How to strip some parts of the string out and put theme into an array?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I know that the match method of String will do if you pass it a regular expression. But the question is how to compose such a regular expression.
Description of the involved string:
1. **Skeleton**:
 The string is composed in such structure:
'UNION(xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,...)'
2. **xxx**:
 The '**xxx**' part is like 
'DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF)', or 
'DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", FILTER(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), ALL), "name" = "adf"), ALL)'.
The DESCENDANTS string might contain several DESCENDANTS string like itself. The structure of a DESCENDANTS string is like 'DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF)'. 
Now the question is how to strip the '**xxx**' parts out of the union string?
**Input:**
'UNION(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF),DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", FILTER(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), ALL), "name" = "adf"), ALL))'
**Output:**
['DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF)', 'DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", FILTER(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), ALL), "name" = "adf"), ALL)']

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to show a complete sample input (nothing *too* long) and its corresponding desired output? I, for one, am not sure if you want to get the smallest pieces from the inner strings, or just stop at the highest level.

Comment: @nnnnnn for your information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some regular expression would fit better but I think small parser fits enough.

```
string = 'UNION(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF),DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", FILTER(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), ALL), "name" = "adf"), ALL))';

s = string.substring(6, string.length -1); //we strip out the 'union' and its parentheses

//Let's parse the children
children = [];
depth = 0;//number of parentheses we pass
while( s.length) {
    var i =0;
    for(i; i < s.length; i++) {
        if(s[i] == "(") {
         depth++;
        }
        if(s[i] == ")") {
         depth--;
        }
        if(s[i] == "," && depth == 0) {
        break;
        }

    }
    children.push(s.substring(0, i));
    s = s.substring(i+1);
}
console.log(children); // ['DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), SELF)', 'DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", FILTER(DESCENDANTS("U0EXMDAW", MEMBERS("U0EXMDAW"), ALL), "name" = "adf"), ALL)']
```

See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/me1k8tbt/1/

Comment: Absolutely, I figured out a solution very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parseSelectedFormulas(sMemberFormula) {
  var selectedFormulas = [],
   formulaString,
   leftParenthesises = [];
  
  if (-1 === sMemberFormula.indexOf("UNION")) {
   selectedFormulas.push(sMemberFormula);
  } else {
   formulaString = sMemberFormula.substring(6, sMemberFormula.length-1);
   for(var i = 0; i < formulaString.length; i++) {
    var char = formulaString.charAt(i);
    switch(char) {
     case "(":
      leftParenthesises.push(i);
      break;
     case ")":
      if (leftParenthesises.length > 1) 
       leftParenthesises.pop();
      else {
       selectedFormulas.push(formulaString.substring(0, i+1));
       leftParenthesises = [];
       if (i !== formulaString.length)
        formulaString = formulaString.substring(i+2);
       else 
        formulaString = "";
       i = -1;
      }
      break;
     default: break;
    }
   }
  }
  return selectedFormulas;
 }
```